# How to add dynamic CSS style sheet for single xhtml file

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have requirement to add two CSS style sheet classes in a single `xhtml`.

For example:

I have `display.xhtml` which will be used by two applications, where we need to apply different CSS for each application.

i.e:

If `display.xhtml` opened in application

1. I need to apply `A.css` and if it is opened in application
2. I need to apply `B.css`.

How to handle this or any other approach is there to achieve this?

Comment: What are the applications? Are they different browsers?

Comment: No its not a different browser...display.xhtml is having same fields used by two apps..but look and feel is different for two applications..

Comment: Your question needs more info.

Comment: `display.xhtml` is opened by iframe by the applications?

Comment: i will elaborate more..i have to create one common xhtml which will be used by two applications..xhtml is placed in application1 and same xhtml is included in application2 using Iframe. So in app1 i need to apply one type of css and app2 another type of css.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this.
in the url in app calling the xhtml iframe put a query string, so in app 1 use

```
display.xhtml?style=a
```

and app 2 use

```
 display.xhtml?style=b
```

then in display.xhtml use javascript to get the query and link to the correct stylesheet

```
  <script>
    var style = getUrlVars()["style"]+".css";
   var fileref=document.createElement("link")
   fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
      fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
     fileref.setAttribute("href", style)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.href = "Scripts/ckeditor/contents.css";
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: While the snippet you posted may answer the question, good answers also contain an explanation of the source code. Welcome to stackoverflow, please read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) guide to learn how to create good quality content.